# Spanning tree with chosen leaves

Tags: algorithms, graphs, spanning-trees

I'm working on the following problem:

> Suppose that we're given a connected, undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ with
> edge weights $w_e$ and a subset of vertices $U \subset V$. We want to find
> the lightest spanning tree in which the nodes of $U$ are leaves (there
> may be other leaves as well). We want to do so in $O(|E|\log(|V|))$ time.

Here's my thinking: since every node $v \in U$ must be a leaf, there must exist a vertex $u \in V \setminus U$ that is the source (i.e. each leaf in $U$ is connected to $u$). However, I'm having trouble find a way to do this that doesn't involve running a polynomial time algorithm. Can anyone help?

Comment: See what happens if you make a forest with the lightest edge incident on each element of $U$.

Comment: is there a version of this where G is acyclic?

Answer (score 4):

Hint for idea: Consider the subgraph $G'$ induced by the vertices in $V \setminus U$. Compute its MST $T'$. Then how should you attach the vertices in $U$ to $T'$?

Hint for implementation: To achieve $O(|E| \log |V|)$, you still run ordinary MST on the original graph $G$, but pay special attention to the vertices in $U$.

Comment: That's not a full answer, but a hint that gets you to within a µ from one.

Answer (score 3):

The solution can be found here which is similar to that suggested by @hengxin

[Minimum spanning tree with chosen leaves](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~dda902/336/hw6-sol.pdf)

Outline of the algorithm

1. Generate an induced graph `G'` containing the vertices `V'=V-U` and  the edges `E'` not involving the vertices in `U`
2. Apply Kruskal's algorithm to get `T'= MST(G')`
3. If `T'` does not exist then the solution does not exist
4. Construct an edge set `E" = (u, v)` where `u` belongs to `U` and `v` does not belong to `U`
5. Apply Kruskal's algorithm on `E"` by adding edges to `T'`
6. Return `T'`

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151513/755

Answer (score 0):

I guess a few modification to the graph may close to the answer. The set $U$ must be chosen and they must form the leaves, right? suppose $u \in U$, For every $v$ adjacent to the $u$ find the minimum edge $\{u,v\}$, assign weight $0$ to it and then remove every other edge connected to the $u$. In the result graph every vertex $u \in U$ necessarily form the leaves.

But you must be careful that every two vertices belong to $U$ must be either disconnected or be on at least one cycle in order to form leaves.