# Spanning tree with chosen leaves NP-Complete proof

Tags: np-complete, spanning-trees

I want to prove that the problem described here

[Spanning tree with chosen leaves](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40131/spanning-tree-with-chosen-leaves)

is NP-Complete.

Of course it is in NP, but what problem would be appropriate to reduce to prove NP-Hardness? And how would that work?

Comment: This is my bad. I am fully aware. I am just a bit tired maybe because I am currently studying reductions, and I was so sure that this was an NP-complete problem, so I didn't even see the answers to the topic. :( Sorry for that! Your answer fully makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Just a comment on terminology: you might end up with a spanning forest instead of a spanning tree if you designate a set of leaves. For example, just consider a path where some middle vertex is designated as a leaf.

Answer (score 3):

The question you link to shows that the problem can be solved in polynomial time.  If the problem was NP-complete, then this would prove that P = NP.  Of course, it's a famous open problem to prove that P = NP or P != NP.  Therefore, you shouldn't expect anyone to know of any such proof.

Also, many computer scientists expect P != NP; if they're right, then the problem you list is not NP-complete.