# Wrong Solution for `Spanning tree with chosen leaves` problem

Tags: algorithms, graphs, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-trees

> Suppose that we're given a **connected**, **undirected** graph $G = (V, E)$ with
> edge weights $w_e$ and a subset of vertices $U \subset V$. We want to find
> the lightest spanning tree in which the nodes of $U$ are leaves (they
> may be other leaves as well). We want to do so in $O(|E|\log(|V|))$ time.

I was reading: [Spanning tree with chosen leaves](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40131/spanning-tree-with-chosen-leaves) But I think the solution is totally wrong:

1. Generate an induced graph `G'` containing the vertices `V'=V-U` and  the edges `E'` not involving the vertices in `U`
2. Apply Kruskal's algorithm to get `T'= MST(G')`
3. If `T'` does not exist then the solution does not exist
4. Construct an edge set `E" = (u, v)` where `u` belongs to `U` and `v` does not belong to `U`
5. Apply Kruskal's algorithm on `E"` by adding edges to `T'`
6. Return `T'`

As a counter example, consider the following graph $G=(V,E)$ where: $V={1,2,3,4}, E={(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(2,4)}$ and $U={4}$ where the weight of edges connected to 4 is -100 and 1 for the rest.

It's clear there is no MST in G where vertex 4 is leaf. But the suggested algorithm above will return a solution...

Comment: OK.  Do you have a question?  What is your question?  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question.

Comment: Hello, unregistered user! You are wrong. If you register an account, I will tell you why.